# Spring Boot - Custom Filter/Stateless auth and @Secured annotation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have been struggling with this for over 2 hours with no luck after reading around 10 different articles.
I want to use my custom filter to perform stateless authorization based on roles from DB and @Secured annotation.

Let's start with my example account identified in database by api-key: '6c1bb23e-e24c-41a5-8f12-72d3db0a6979'.
He has following String role fetched from DB: 'FREE_USER_ROLE'.

My filter:

```
public class ApiKeyAuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

private final AccountService accountService;

private final GlobalExceptionsAdvice exceptionAdvice;

private static final String API_KEY_HEADER_FIELD = "X-AUTH-KEY";

public static final List<String> NON_AUTH_END_POINTS
        = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("/Accounts", "/Accounts/Login"));

AntPathMatcher pathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();

public ApiKeyAuthFilter(AccountService accountService, GlobalExceptionsAdvice exceptionAdvice) {
    this.accountService = accountService;
    this.exceptionAdvice = exceptionAdvice;
}

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain fc) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Optional authKey = Optional.ofNullable(request.getHeader(API_KEY_HEADER_FIELD));
    if (!authKey.isPresent()) {
        sendForbiddenErrorMessage(response);
    } else {
        try {
            AccountDTO account = accountService.findByApiKey(authKey.get().toString());
            Set<GrantedAuthority> roles = new HashSet();
            account.getRoles().forEach((singleRole) -> roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(singleRole.getName())));
            Authentication accountAuth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(account.getEmail(), account.getApiKey(),
                    roles);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(accountAuth);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities().forEach((role) -> {
                System.out.println(role.getAuthority());
            });
            fc.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (ElementDoesNotExistException ex) {
            //TODO: Add logging that user tried to falsy authenticate
            sendForbiddenErrorMessage(response);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
    return NON_AUTH_END_POINTS.stream().anyMatch(p -> {
        return pathMatcher.match(p, request.getServletPath())
                && request.getMethod().equals("POST");
    });
}

private void sendForbiddenErrorMessage(HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ErrorDetail error = exceptionAdvice.handleAccessDeniedException();
    resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
    resp.setContentType("application/json");
    resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    resp.getWriter().write(mapper.writeValueAsString(error));
}
```

As You can see I am using X-AUTH-KEY header to retrieve provided apiKey, then I fetch info from Database based on that key and assign appropiate roles into SecurityContextHolder. Until that point everything works. I am sending poper apiKey, DB returns 'FREE_USER_ROLE'.

My @Configuration annotation class. (I bet something is wrong here but I can not tell what):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class ApiKeySecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

AccountService accountService;

GlobalExceptionsAdvice exceptionAdvice;

@Autowired
public ApiKeySecurityConfiguration(AccountService accountService, GlobalExceptionsAdvice exceptionAdvice) {
    this.accountService = accountService;
    this.exceptionAdvice = exceptionAdvice;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    httpSecurity.csrf().disable();

    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(new ApiKeyAuthFilter(accountService, exceptionAdvice), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
}
```

And final piece of puzzle - Controller that uses @Secured:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Accounts")
public class AccountsResource {

   @Secured({"FREE_USER_ROLE"})
   @PutMapping()
   public boolean testMethod() {
       return true;
   }
}
```

I have tried with both 'FREE_USER_ROLE' and 'ROLE_FREE_USER_ROLE'. Everytime I get 403 Forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

So I have spent some more time yesterday on that and I have managed to get it working with @PreAuthorize annotation. Posting code below because it may be useful to someone in future.

Filter:

```
@Component
public class ApiKeyAuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

private final AccountService accountService;

private final GlobalExceptionsAdvice exceptionAdvice;

private static final String API_KEY_HEADER_FIELD = "X-AUTH-KEY";

public static final List<String> NON_AUTH_END_POINTS
        = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("/Accounts", "/Accounts/Login"));

AntPathMatcher pathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();

@Autowired
public ApiKeyAuthFilter(AccountService accountService, GlobalExceptionsAdvice exceptionAdvice) {
    this.accountService = accountService;
    this.exceptionAdvice = exceptionAdvice;
}

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain fc) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Optional authKey = Optional.ofNullable(request.getHeader(API_KEY_HEADER_FIELD));
    if (!authKey.isPresent()) {
        sendForbiddenErrorMessage(response);
    } else {
        try {
            AccountDTO account = accountService.findByApiKey(authKey.get().toString());
            Set<GrantedAuthority> roles = new HashSet();
            account.getRoles().forEach((singleRole) -> roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(singleRole.getName())));
            Authentication accountAuth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(account.getEmail(), account.getApiKey(),
                    roles);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(accountAuth);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities().forEach((role) -> {
                System.out.println(role.getAuthority());
            });
            fc.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (ElementDoesNotExistException ex) {
            //TODO: Add logging that user tried to falsy authenticate
            sendForbiddenErrorMessage(response);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
    return NON_AUTH_END_POINTS.stream().anyMatch(p -> {
        return pathMatcher.match(p, request.getServletPath())
                && request.getMethod().equals("POST");
    });
}

private void sendForbiddenErrorMessage(HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ErrorDetail error = exceptionAdvice.handleAccessDeniedException();
    resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
    resp.setContentType("application/json");
    resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    resp.getWriter().write(mapper.writeValueAsString(error));
}

}
```

Configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ApiKeySecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.
        csrf().disable().
        sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
}
```

Secured methods and methods allowed for anybody to use:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Accounts")
public class AccountsResource {

@PostMapping
@PreAuthorize("permitAll()")
public boolean forAll() {
    return true;
}


@PutMapping()
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('FREE_USER_ROLE')")
public boolean testMethod() {
    return true;
}
}
```